# Find the maximum number of possible real roots of the equation $a x^4+ b x^3+ x^2+ x+1=0$ is equal to where $a \ne 0$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The question goes on like this :

"Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a \ne 0$. Then the maximum number of possible real roots of the equation $ax^4+bx^3+x^2+x+1=0$  is equal to "

My attempt:

- First I differentiate wrt $x$, but due to variable: $a$ and $b$, I can't make any direct conclusion
- Also by writing $-ax^4-bx^3=x^2+x+1$, I could draw graph of RHS but not of LHS.

Please help with this problem in shortest way out.

Comment: Do you want to find the max number in terms of $a,b$? or you just want to find max number.

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags. I have replaced them with appropriate ones. This has nothing to do with either linear algebra or elementary number theory.

Comment: @AngaeMT just maximum number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=0$ cannot be a root, so we can equivalently investigate the roots of its reciprocal polynomial $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+bx+a$. Now $p''(x) = 12x^2+6x+2$ doesn't have real roots, so at best $p'(x)$ has one real root, which means $p(x)$ can have atmost two real roots..

Now it suffices to note that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1$ is negative at the origin, so two real roots is clearly possible.

Comment: @ Macavity Umm one thing, in the question it was $$p(x)=a{x}^4+b{x}^3+{x}^2+x+1$$ Then $$ p''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2$$, so If b and a adjusted, we can easily get real values. This pattern continues till $$p''''(x)=24a $$which is a constant. And hence, this equation can actually have all 4 possible roots$ ∈ R$ . @SavageTomato it infact can have 4 real roots for certain a and b values. You can try it out in Desmos

Comment: @Gwen By "easily", do you have examples of $a$ and $b$ that give more real roots?

Comment: @Gwen If $\alpha$ is a root of $ax^4+bx^3+x^2+x+1$, then $1/\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+bx+a$, hence the number of real roots is equivalent in both cases.  As $p(x)$ cannot have more than two real roots, neither can the original polynomial.  Read up on "reciprocal polynomials" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial.

Comment: @Gwen also note the condition on $p’’$ is a necessary one, not sufficient. Because it has real roots does not guarantee existence of four roots for $p$, you need to demonstrate it.

Comment: @Gwen For the original equation $f(x) = ax^4+bx^3+x^2+x+1 = 0$, the second derivative $f''(x) = 12ax^2+6bx+2$ may have two real roots and give two inflection points. But whether the lower terms of $f$ (i.e. $x+1$) allow more than $1$ stationary points and more than $2$ real roots? This is less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$  be real roots of

$ax^4+bx^3+x^2+x+1=0$.

Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\beta},\frac{1}{\gamma},\frac{1}{\delta}$ be roots of

$\displaystyle x^4+x^3+x^2+bx+a=0.$

Then $\displaystyle \sum \bigg(\frac{1}{\alpha}\bigg)^2=\sum \frac{1}{\alpha^2}+2\sum \frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta}$

$\displaystyle (-1)^2=\sum \frac{1}{\alpha^2}+2(1)\Longrightarrow \sum \frac{1}{\alpha^2}=-1<0$

So not all roots are real.

So maximum $2$ real roots exists

Answer (score 0):

I will try for a longer answer a bit later, but my first step would be to "depress" the quartic to remove the $x^{3}$ term using the transformation $x'=x+\frac{b}{4a}$.

From here, I would try the quartic discriminant

$\Delta=16c^{4}e-4c^{3}d^{2}-128c^{2}e^{2}+144cd^{2}e-27d^{4}+256e^{3}$

Comment: @jjagmath - not sure this helps since the question is not about the number of positive/negative roots, but rather the total number. Descarte's rule of signs is problematic when the degree of the polynomial is even.